# Linking jsPDF to const ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

Hi I'm trying to link an export default class to a Link, the external default class should create a PDF whit jsPDF, and the Link is dynamically generated by a firebase database.

I've trying all the options, but nothing generate the PDF. When I click the link nothing happens

```
// The list JS

import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import PrintProject from './PrintProject'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProjectSummary = ({ project }) => {



return (

<tr>
  <td>{project.name}</td>
  <td>{project.modAce}</td>
  <td>{project.coach}</td>
  <td><Link to={'/project/' + project.id} key={project.id}><i className="material-icons">visibility</i></Link></td>
  <td><Route path='/print/' component={PrintProject} ><i class="material-icons">save_alt</i></Route></td>
</tr>

 )



 }



export default ProjectSummary
```

The jsPDF

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import PDF, { Text, AddPage, Line, Image, Table, Html } from 'jspdf-react'


export default class Print extends Component {
    render () {
```

Thanks for all.